# Problema external_reference mercadopago

Tags: mercadopago

tengo un problema, creo un boton con la libreria de MP y cobra y todo perfect, pero crei que podia enviar enviar un id para despues validar por el external reference

creo el boton

```
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
  $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
  $item->id = "COD1234";                 //Aqui crei que podia enviar el id de pedido
  $item->title = "Arreglo Floral";
  $item->quantity = 1;
  $item->currency_id = "PEN";
  $item->unit_price = $totalx1;
  $payer = new MercadoPago\Payer();
  $payer->email = "recibos@hola.com";
  $preference->items = array($item);
  $preference->payer = $payer;
  $preference->save();
```

y ejecuto mi boton

```
<div id="oculto_visa" style="display: none">
                            <button class="order-button hvr-bounce-out"  type="button">
                            <a href="<?php echo $preference->init_point; ?>">
                            COMPRAR AHORA
                            </a>
                            </button>
                            </div>
```

Cobra y todo bien, como hago para enviar un codigo de pedido a ese formulario y luego validar en mi sistema que fue pagado ese recibo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías agregar la siguiente linea en tu código

```
$preference->external_reference = "3114";
```

Quedaría así

```
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
  $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
  $item->id = "COD1234";                 //Aqui crei que podia enviar el id de pedido
  $item->title = "Arreglo Floral";
  $item->quantity = 1;
  $item->currency_id = "PEN";
  $item->unit_price = $totalx1;
  $payer = new MercadoPago\Payer();
  $payer->email = "recibos@hola.com";
  $preference->items = array($item);
  $preference->payer = $payer;
  $preference->external_reference = " **ACA VA EL ID** "; 
  $preference->save();
```

Luego tenes que configurar la url donde vas a recibir las notificaciones de mercadopago, es decir una vex que meradopago realice el cobro a donde te va a informar que se realizó

Esto se realiza en el siguiente link

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications

El archivo que recibe los datos debe tener un formato similar a este

```
  require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';

header("Status: 200");

    MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken("**********************************");
 $bd=conectar_bd();

    $merchant_order = null;

    switch($_GET["topic"]) {
        case "payment":

            $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::find_by_id($_GET["id"]);
            // Get the payment and the corresponding merchant_order reported by the IPN.

    }

    $paid_amount = 0;
    if ($payment){

              if ($payment->status == 'approved'){

              }

              if ($payment->status == 'in_process'){


              }

              if ($payment->status == 'rejected'){


                 }

             }
```

Este ultimo código puede variar segun tus necesidades pero creo que es una buena base.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido Federico, podrías dar más detalle  en tu respuesta? Ayudará al OP a entenderlo mejor... Date una vuelta por [answer] para mas información